# MongoDB query for related records

Tags: sql-server-2008, node.js, mongodb

I have a blog application. I need to make a **MongoDB query** (SQL is *fine*, I'll translate it), to get a specific post in the blog, and the immediate posts made before and after that post.

For instance, given this list of posts:

```
12/01/13 - Foo
15/01/13 - Bar
17/01/13 - Baz
27/01/13 - Taz
```

How do I write a query so that I get one of these, i.g `Bar`, **and the immediate siblings** `Foo` and `Baz`?

I'd like to do this *without making three different queries* to the database, for performance reasons.

In my application I fetch a single post like this:

```
model.findOne({
    date: {
        $gte: new Date(2013, 0, 15),
        $lt: new Date(2013, 0, 15, 24)
    },
    slug: 'Bar'
}, function(result){
    return { entry: result };
});
```

Comment: Given your search criteria not being a specific document (instead a date range), this isn't a good fit for a single MongoDB request. Even in an RDBMS, this would likely need a sneaky subquery. :)  Why are 3 queries a problem?

Comment: How do you find the initial item? by Id, Date or some other criteria?

Comment: @Ian two ways actually, by Id, or by Date + Slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility (involving 2 queries, one to find the primary post, and the second to find the nearest doc):

- Treat the data/posts as if it were a doubly-linked list.
- You'll need to store reference IDs as links to the "previous" and "next" posts in each post document (array). This makes inserts a tiny more complex, but inserting a "new" blog post by date somewhere in the past seems unlikely.
- Index the link field
- Search for documents having the id of the primary document [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) the link field